# find the latest task from the dataframe columns based on the task role and replace the column value with the latest column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe  with the following columns

```
df1:
Task Start Date  |  Task Finish Date  |  Task Role
01-01-2021           01-03-2021            Lead
01-04-2021           02-02-2021            Team member
01-04-2021           02-23-2021            Unknown
```

I want to create another column 'Origin Role' based on the following conditions:

if the Task Role is lead/anything then skip (fill the same Task Role into the new column ('Origin Role');

else only if Task Role is Unknown then:

- consider the Task Start Date of the record with Task Role 'Unknown' and find the latest record(if there are multiple) with its Task Finish Date <=(less than or equal to) Task Start Date (unknown role).
- Then fill in the Task role of the latest role in place of the unknown role in the new column 'Origin Role'.

My expectation:

```
df1:
Task Start Date  |  Task Finish Date  |  Task Role       | Origin Role
01-01-2021           01-03-2021            Lead              Lead
01-04-2021           02-02-2021            Team member       Team Member
01-04-2021           02-23-2021            Unknown           Lead
```

Comment: I think you meant "Task Finish Date >= Task Start Date"? How do we define the latest record? With the Task Start or the Task Finish?

Comment: the latest record as in the record that just finished before the task with the unknown role started.  So, Task Finish Date <= Task Start Date.

Comment: Ah, I got confused because your Task Finish Date for Leader was 05-05-2021 in the first table.

Comment: Sorry Michael my bad! let me update it real quick

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
# ensure datetime
df[['Task Start Date', 'Task Finish Date']] = \
df[['Task Start Date', 'Task Finish Date']].apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=False)


df['Origin Role'] = df['Task Role'].replace({'Unknown': np.nan}).fillna(
    pd.merge_asof(df['Task Start Date'].sort_values().reset_index(),
                  df[['Task Finish Date', 'Task Role']]
                    .loc[lambda d: d['Task Role'].ne('Unknown')]
                    .sort_values(by='Task Finish Date'),
                  left_on='Task Start Date', right_on='Task Finish Date',
                  ).set_index('index')['Task Role']
)
```

Steps:

- [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) "Unknown" by NaN
- sort values by date
- merge on the closest previous date, ignoring "Unknown"
- [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with this value

Output:

```
  Task Start Date Task Finish Date    Task Role  Origin Role
0      2021-01-01       2021-01-03         Lead         Lead
1      2021-01-04       2021-02-02  Team member  Team member
2      2021-01-04       2021-02-23      Unknown         Lead
```

Comment: ValueError: Merge keys contain null values on left side 
I am getting this error. I tried fillna() and dropna() but unknowingly both doesn't seem to work.